# Adding a class to previous selection in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 items..

div1 - div2 -div3

div1 has class "current" by default.. once a click is made in the form, .current is removed from previous div and added to div2 (the current div)..

```
    function tab_selection(step)
    {
        $(step).parent().find('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(step).addClass('current');
    }
```

How can I add a "finished" class to the previous steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what best solution is because you didn't post html or what your code flow is, but based on your comment you could try `prevAll`.

```
function tab_selection(step)
{
    $(step).prevAll('div').addClass('finished');
    $(step).parent().find('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(step).addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: Tried that already and that is obvious.. but it does not work because on page load, div1 already has "current" class.  and thus it automatically starts off with class="current finished"

Comment: @Josh - you'll have to provide more context to your question then. There are many ways to solve this, but with no html structure and not even knowing how the page loads or progresses through the steps it's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stepping forward one element at a time, and you're adding "finished" as a class whenever you leave an element, you can simply deal with `.current` and whatever comes next each iteration:

```
$(".current")
    .removeClass("current")
    .addClass("finished")
.next()
    .addClass("current");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4VwA5/